# Find the cumulative distribution function $ _[t]$ given $Y=1/X$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let X random variable have the following density function:

> $$f_X(x) = \begin{cases} 3/2x^4 & x \leq -1 \\
>  0 & -1 < x < 1 \\ 
> 1/x^3 & x \geq 1\end{cases} $$

Given $Y=1/x$, Find the cumulative distribution function $ _[t]$ of $ $

Partly solution:

range for Y is $[-1,0)\cup  (0,1]$

case 1: $0 < t \le 1$

$ _[t]  = Pr[1/X \le t] = Pr[X<  0] + Pr[X \ge 1/t]$

case 2: $-1 \le t <  0$

$ _[t]  = Pr[1/X \le t] = Pr[1/t \le X<  0] = Pr[X \le 0] - Pr[X \le 1/t]$

My question:

Where did $Pr[X<  0]$ come from?

Comment: $\frac1X\le t<0\implies X<0.$

Comment: $\frac 1 X \leq t$ is not the same as $X \geq \frac  1 t$. You have to take the sign of $X$ into account.